# Validar un clave encriptada con un control login

Tags: .net

Tengo un control login el cual no me permite iniciar sesión ya que mi campo clave esta encriptada con el método getsha256 y se guarda en la base de datos y al momento que el control hace la validación el campo de la clave no tiene el mismo valor que en la base de datos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
    protected void Login1_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
{
    if (objSefuridad.UsuarioVerificaSistema(Login1.UserName.ToString(), Login1.Password.ToString()))
    { 
        Session["sOpe_Usuario"] = Login1.UserName.ToString().ToUpper();
        Session["sOpe_Clave1"] = Login1.UserName.ToString().ToUpper();

        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("UserInfo");
        cookie["usuario"] = Session["sOpe_Nombre"].ToString();
        cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5.0);
        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
        FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(Login1.UserName, true);
    }
    else
    {
        System.Text.StringBuilder jScript = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        jScript.Append("<Script>" + Environment.NewLine);
        jScript.Append("alert('Usuario o Contraseña invalida');" + Environment.NewLine);
        jScript.Append("</Script>" + Environment.NewLine);
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Bookmark", jScript.ToString());
    }
}

public bool UsuarioVerificaSistema(string usuario, string password)
{
    bool bResult = false;
    StringBuilder sbSQL = new StringBuilder();

    sbSQL.Append("SELECT Ope_Usuario, Ope_Clave1 ");
    sbSQL.Append("FROM operacion.usuarios ");
    sbSQL.Append("WHERE Ope_Usuario = '" + usuario + "' ");
    sbSQL.Append("AND Ope_Clave1 =" + password + "");

    SqlConnection connDB = new SqlConnection();
    SqlDataReader drCon = null;

    if (objCnx.Conecta("conn", connDB) == CONSTANTES.BASE_ABIERTA)
    {
        drCon = objCnx.DisparaSQLRD(sbSQL.ToString(), connDB);
        if (drCon != null)
        {
            if (drCon.HasRows)
            {
                bResult = true;
            }
            drCon.Close();
        }
        objCnx.Desconecta(connDB);
    }
    return bResult;
}
```

¿Saben como podría validar mi clave del login con el campo clave1 de mi base de datos que esta encriptada?

Comment: Saludos. No es posible; las funciones hash no son reversibles; te sugiero mejor actualizar el campo mediante proceso que tu hagas/uses en lo siguiente de tu aplicación.